# Test/Sandbox Environment for Google My Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I just started with using Google My Business API and was able to perform the get operations just to verify that my Oauth setup is right. Now I want to add a location using the post method for GMB Add location API but before I push my code to production I want to test out this request. Do we have any testing/sandbox environment for Google My Business API testing ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here for reference I guess if you are using third party tools(Integromat/ Zapier) to make the API Call, the best way is to validate your request by passing in query parameter: validateOnly = True

Answer (score 0):

According to their doc, this is not possible. please read more [here](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request)

Comment: Hey Nikkolai , Thanks for the response. I checked with the Google support team too, and yes they dont have any sandbox environment. However For anyone coming here for reference I guess if you are using third party tools(Integromat/ Zapier) to make the API Call, the best way is to validate your request by passing in query parameter: validateOnly = True