# Testing and development for Google My Business API

Tags: google-my-business-api

According to Google, they have not sandbox or test accounts for developers to use and also state that you can not make fake business accounts.  What kind of workarounds have you used to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Location group and location management can be tested with non-live GMB entities (so just don't publish them to Google Maps). Reviews etc. is a challenge though - instead of sending actual requests, you'll have to mock responses yourself, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Found this: [Test/Sandbox Environment for Google My Business API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788751/test-sandbox-environment-for-google-my-business-api)

> For anyone coming here for reference I guess if you are using third party tools(Integromat/ Zapier) to make the API Call, the best way is to validate your request by passing in query parameter: validateOnly = True